# Merging/Combining 2 text files according to numeric field

Tags: text-processing, awk, columns, join

I have 2 text files

file_1:

```
14595|Age 35|Salary xx|Position ax|2013|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5
14649|Age 30|Salary xx|Position az|2015|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5
```

file_2:

```
14595|Address xx|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
14649|Address xxxz|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
```

I want a way to look up file_1 first column (the numeric one) and find its match in file_2 and combine info of both files into file_3 without the numeric key field so the output is like

file_3

```
Age 35|Salary xx|Position ax|2013|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xx|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
Age 30|Salary xx|Position az|2015|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xxxz|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `join`:

```
$ join -t'|' file_1 file_2
14595|Age 35|Salary xx|Position ax|2013|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xx|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
14649|Age 30|Salary xx|Position az|2015|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xxxz|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
```

`-t` indicates the field separator.

In order to join works, files must te sorted. You can use `sort` for it.

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"}NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}{$1=a[$1]}1' file_1 file_2
14595|Age 35|Salary xx|Position ax|2013|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xx|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
14649|Age 30|Salary xx|Position az|2015|Info 1|Info 2|Info 3|Info 4|Info 5|Address xxxz|Info 6|Info 7|Info 8
```

Comment: because [your answer returns the rest of file2](http://paste.ubuntu.com/9544206/)